# What does origins mean in "chrome.permissions.request"?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Google Chrome extension.

The optional permission is what I need.

According to the documentation [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/permissions#property-Permissions-origins) The user can request permission on demand. And the code is like this:

```
document.querySelector('#my-button').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // Permissions must be requested from inside a user gesture, like a button's
  // click handler.
  chrome.permissions.request({
    permissions: ['tabs'],
    origins: ['http://www.google.com/']
  }, function(granted) {
    // The callback argument will be true if the user granted the permissions.
    if (granted) {
      doSomething();
    } else {
      doSomethingElse();
    }
  });
});
```

What does the `origins: ['http://www.google.com/']` mean in the object that are passing to `chrome.permissions.request`?

Comment: Origin is a part of the URL like protocol://hostname

Comment: What if I change `www.google.com` to some other domain like `www.yahoo.com`, what would happen?

Comment: 1) You'll see a different site in the dialog, 2) a different site will be allowed for the extension to access.

Comment: Does that have anything to do with my extension? I am still confused. The permission is for "tabs" and has nothing to do with Google or any detailed website.

Comment: Then specify `"<all_urls>"` or don't specify the `origins` parameter at all.